# Multiple AppSettings files, is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, appsettings

I want to create 3 AppSettings config files:

- Database.config
- Messages.config
- Global.config

And after add in my App.config:

```
<appSettings file="Database.config" />
<appSettings file="Messages.config" />
<appSettings file="Global.config" />
```

But when I try to access a key that there is in one of three files with the `ConfigurationManager`, I got the following error:

> Configuration system failed to initialize. Sections must only appear once per config file.

I cannot have more than one AppSettings config file?

Comment: Define different config sections, why you want add extra files? appconfig file is one for all of running projects root.

Comment: Most readable to final user that 'll change some values. Only one file, i'll have a big file, and i don't want it.

Comment: You could also use some xml file to do your configuration, but  config file with 200-300 lines of code is not bad;)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575144/accessing-appsettings-from-multiple-web-config-files

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can't have more than one appsettings because that's the name of a section. You can add a new section though that uses the same kind of section definition as appsettings. E.g.,

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="DatabaseConfig" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </configSections>
    ....
    <DatabaseConfig>
       <add key="Whatever" value="stuff"/>
    </DatabaseConfig>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can i add the <DatabaseConfig> in another file? My goal is put each config in a different file.

Comment: Yep. Absolutely. Works exactly the same way as appsettings.

Comment: And to access with the configuration manager? How can i reach this? (because with appSettings i do: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"])

Comment: NameValueCollection settings = (NameValueCollection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("DatabaseConfig");

Answer (score 49):

Code for separate file:

Web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="DatabaseConfig" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="MessageConfig" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="GlobalConfig" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>

<DatabaseConfig configSource="database.config">
</DatabaseConfig>

<MessageConfig configSource="message.config">
</MessageConfig>

<GlobalConfig configSource="global.config">
</GlobalConfig>
```

database.config:

```
<DatabaseConfig>
  <add key="Name" value="ServerName" />
</DatabaseConfig>
```

etc...

Can be accessed via code like this:

```
var databaseConfiguration = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("DatabaseConfig");
string name = databaseConfiguration["Name"];
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed for app version