# Accessing appSettings from multiple Web.config files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I am designing an ASP.NET MVC4 Web App project. In the root of my project, I have the customary default `Web.config` file with my corresponding elements. In particular, I have a few `appSettings` elements defined. As an example excerpt to demonstrate this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</appSettings>
```

Naturally, I can access this element within code using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]`. This works perfectly for me. However, I am creating a NuGet package alongside my project. The package is installed within its own directory under my project's `Areas` directory. Here, in my package's root, I have another `Web.config` file. This is so that, when another user imports the NuGet package, the configuration for the package resources is native to the package. Let the package's `Web.config` contain the following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="dirEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Just to clarify in terms of relative paths, I now have two Web.config files, one at `./Web.config` and one at `./Areas/PackageName/Web.config`.

Within my package, I want to retrieve the value for `dirEnabled`. To do so, I make the call: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dirEnabled"]`. However, this throws an error. It appears as if only the collection of appSettings is being retrieved from `./Web.config` and not my package config file. **Is it at all possible to grab the appSettings collection from my package's config file rather than the project root config file?**

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351106/multiple-appsettings-files-is-it-possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out! To use a different config file, incorporate `WebConfigurationmanager`. So, to access the appSettings of `./Areas/PackageName/Web.config`, simply use:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Areas/PackageName");
string dirE = config.AppSettings.Settings["dirEnabled"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
<appSettings file="<Path_To_Second_Web.Config>">
   ...
</appSettings >
```

in your project's Web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is still throwing an error indicating that it cannot find the value, however.

Comment: You will maybe find something here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx