# Sub Web.config in Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I'm working on a huge MVC 4 project. I'm using Area and it's great.

But, I want, for each Areas, use a custom Web.config.

For example, this is my structure :

```
Root
Web.config
|
----Areas
--------MyArea_1
--------MyArea_2
----Web.config
```

In my root Web.config, i've all the connections. In my Sub Web.config, i want to add "appSettings" that concern only Areas.

In my sub Web.config, for example :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyArea_1_Param1" value="1"/>
    <add key="MyArea_1_Param2" value="2"/>

    <add key="MyArea_2_Param1" value="1"/>
</appSettings>
```

For the moment, i've put all of my parameters in the root Web.config.

How can I make a link between my different Web.config?

------UPDATE--------

I've try to put this code in my Sub Web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<location path="MyArea_1">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="MyArea_1_Param1" value="1"/>
        <add key="MyArea_1_Param2" value="2"/>
    </appSettings>
</location>
```

A I put this file, here :

```
Root
Web.config
|
----Areas
--------MyArea_1
--------MyArea_2
----Web.config <- Here
```

I already try here to :

```
Root
Web.config
|
----Areas
--------MyArea_1
------------Web.config
--------MyArea_2
```

But i'm still getting a "NullReferenceException" when I try to read the key value "MyArea_1_Param1"

My code for read the key value :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyArea_1_Param1"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
<location path="myarea">
  <appsetttings>
    <add key="MyArea_1_Param1" value="1"/>
  </appsettings>
</location>
```

and put these web.configs under area directories

To access your web.config in given area, you can use code like this:

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Areas/MyArea1/Views/Web.config").AppSettings.Settings["MyArea1_Param1"].Value
```

Comment: Please, see my update. i've try, maybe badly, because i still have a NullReferenceException error.

Answer (score 1):

Web.config file for each area is placed in the Views folder of this area by default. You can use it to add custom settings that will be visible only in that particular area.

**Update**

Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595625/2853600)?

Comment: i've try it before but i've a "NullReferenceException" when i try to read my key value.