# Add more than one relative path in webconfig appSetting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can i specify more than one relative file path in appSetting path attribute in asp.net web.config file. where my appsetting keys are residing in two different file .

```
<appSettings file="Web.User.config">
 </appSettings >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple AppSettings files, is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351106/multiple-appsettings-files-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference more than one file path for appSettings. appSettings is a section and you cannot have more than one of those. However, you can add a new section which works like the appSettings section. Example:

```
<configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="CustomConfig" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </configSections>
    ....
<CusTomConfig>
    <add key="Key1" value="Value1"/>
</CustomConfig>
```

Then, you can access that section with:

```
NameValueCollection settings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CustomConfig");
```

A second option is using a [Custom Configuration Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx). This will require some boilerplate code (as shown in the MSDN documentation) but you will be able to access setting values with properties, rather than referencing them with strings like `settings["Key1"]`.